# Google Maps API V3 - Check whether a co-ordinate is near a DirectionRoute in the backend

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API V3 to create a custom map in my Java Web application with MySql as database.

I have a feature to add custom markers through front end and saving the marker coordinate(lat/lng) in the backend.

I am planning to add the direction search feature in the frontend and save the result(single route) in the backend.

Whenever a marker is added, i want to find out all the routes(pre-saved) which is near to the location of the marker.

Can someone suggest me an efficient way to store the route detail and a way to compare it with marker coordinates.

Note :

I have learned about Way points and overview_path but both of them are not providing me the full list of coordinates to compare with marker coordinates.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you save the coordinates of your way points in a database you can use  [**Haversine formula**](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) 
to search nearest waypoint to your marker
This query  incorporates the formula and uses  [**PDO**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT  name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM mytable HAVING distance < ? ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 1");
    // Assign parameters
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$center_lat);//lat coordinate of user
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$center_lng);//lng coordinate of user
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$center_lat);//lat coordinate of user
    $stmt->bindParam(4,$radius);//Radius in miles
```

Comment: I want to store about 10K routes and the way points for each route may be in hundreds to thousands so the number of points will be lakhs. Is it efficient to store all the way points as it is or is there any other way store only minimal set of points? And does the MySql table perform well for querying with this huge set of data?

Comment: @Deepak This query took 2.08 secs to run on a 500,000 row MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

When you save the route in your database use geohashing to calculate all bounding boxes the route goes trough and store them in another table (with 2 fields - geohash,route_id as PRIMARY).

When you search for routes calculate all bounding boxes which are in a circle with the user location as center and the distance as radius, then use a query with `geohash IN (circle_hashes)`.